# Formatting date (difference )- Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement , to get the out put in the following format when we give two dates as input:

- Input 1 --> `sysdate`
- Input 2 --> `to_date('10-OCT-2014')` --> this is dynamic

Output :

```
11 days 00 Hours 27 Minutes 41 Seconds
```

The seconds could be an optional one.
currently am using

```
select  TRIM (TRAILING '.' FROM (TRIM (BOTH '0' FROM (TRIM (LEADING '+' FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL (
                                                                                                (24
                                                                                                 * 60
                                                                                                 * 60
                                                                                                 * (SYSDATE   -                                                                                                
                                                                                                       to_date('10-OCT-2014'))),
                                                                                                'second')))))) from dual
```

but the output will be like  "11 00:27:41" but the requirement is "11 days 00 Hours 27 Minutes 41 Seconds"

It can be a query or a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always appreciate questions related to datetime formatting with SQL. There are so many stupid hacks in the world (e.g. converting to strings and doing string operations)....

As your question is oracle specific, the answer by Multisync should be accepted. But if someone looks for a version that does not need the numtodsinterval function (for portability or something else), you could also try this more verbose solution:

```
with base as (
    select abs(sysdate-to_date('2014-10-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) as diff
    from dual
), days as (
    select floor(diff) part,
           diff-floor(diff) remainder
    from base
), hours as (
    select floor(remainder*24) part,
           remainder*24-floor(remainder*24) remainder
   from days
), minutes as (
    select floor(remainder*60) part,
           remainder*60-floor(remainder*60) remainder
    from hours
), seconds as (
    select floor(remainder*60) part
    from minutes
)
select days.part||' days '||
       lpad(hours.part, 2, '0')||' hours '||
       lpad(minutes.part, 2, '0')||' minutes '||
       lpad(seconds.part, 2, '0')||' seconds'
from days, hours, minutes, seconds;
```

**Extended solution that respects the direction of the difference**

```
with base as (
    select sysdate now, to_date('2014-10-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') otherdate
    from dual
), diff as (
    select abs(now-otherdate) as value,
           sign(now-otherdate) as dir
    from base
), days as (
    select floor(value) part,
           value-floor(value) remainder
    from diff
), hours as (
    select floor(remainder*24) part,
           remainder*24-floor(remainder*24) remainder
   from days
), minutes as (
    select floor(remainder*60) part,
           remainder*60-floor(remainder*60) remainder
    from hours
), seconds as (
    select floor(remainder*60) part
    from minutes
)
select case dir
    when 1 then 'before '||strbuilder.intervalstr
    when -1 then 'after '||strbuilder.intervalstr
    else 'now' end
from (
    select days.part||' days '||
           lpad(hours.part, 2, '0')||' hours '||
           lpad(minutes.part, 2, '0')||' minutes '||
           lpad(seconds.part, 2, '0')||' seconds ' as intervalstr
    from days, hours, minutes, seconds
) strbuilder, diff;
```

Comment: How do you handle negative intervals in this solution?

Comment: Intervals (or distances) are not negative by definition - from a mathematical point of view. If you want to output the "direction" of the difference, you can add the information depending on the signum of the difference. See my extended solution (Update)

Answer (score 3):

```
select extract(day from ds_int) || ' days ' 
    || extract(hour from ds_int) || ' Hours '  
    || extract(minute from ds_int) || ' Minutes '  
    || extract(second from ds_int) || ' Second'  
from
(select numtodsinterval(sysdate - to_date('10-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'day') ds_int from dual);
```

With trailing "0" (won't work with negative interval)

```
select extract(day from ds_int) || ' days ' 
    || lpad(extract(hour from ds_int), 2, 0) || ' Hours '  
    || lpad(extract(minute from ds_int), 2, 0) || ' Minutes '  
    || lpad(extract(second from ds_int), 2, 0) || ' Second'  
from
(select numtodsinterval(sysdate - to_date('10-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'day') ds_int from dual);
```

There is a restriction however - day may contain 9 digits (maximum)

It's better to avoid using a construction such "to_date('10-OCT-2014')" - result may be unpredictable (depending on NLS settings of your session). Better define a mask "to_date('10-10-2014', 'DD-MM-YYYY')"

Comment: Please add lpad(..., 2, '0') to hours, minutes and seconds (see example output in original post)

Comment: "(won't work with negative interval)" - then just wrap your "sysdate-to_date(...)" into an abs() function :)

Comment: @UniversE yes, but I don't know what the OP wants (maybe to show negative)

Comment: @UniversE, `ABS(SYSTIMESTAMP-TO_TIMESTAMP(...))` does not work with TIMESTAMPS: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`. Also perhaps he want the `-` at the very beginning of the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should better work with `TIMESTAMP` rathe than `DATE` data type when you like to work with `INTERVAL` values. However, `NUMTODSINTERVAL` should be fine as well.

`TO_CHAR` does not work properly for `INTERVAL` datatypes, the output format is fix. Thus you can do it regular expression, e.g.

```
SELECT 
regexp_replace(systimestamp - timestamp '2014-10-10 00:00:00', 
   '.?0*(\d+) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*', 
   '\1 days \2 hours \3 minutes \4 seconds') from dual;
```

or if you prefer NUMTODSINTERVAL:

```
SELECT 
REGEXP_REPLACE(NUMTODSINTERVAL(24*60*60* (SYSDATE-TO_DATE('10-OCT-2014')), 'SECOND'), 
    '.?0*(\d+) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).*', 
    '\1 days \2 hours \3 minutes \4 seconds') 
FROM dual;
```

[EXTRACT (datetime)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) would be suitable only if your interval is **always** positive, otherwise you get the `-` at each component.

Comment: Thank you Wernfried.. but the second value come from table which is in date  datatype. so, can you help me how to change the data type to time stamp to carry out this operation  ?

Comment: You should never do string operations on datetime values - never!

Comment: Thank you Winfred , Thank you UniverseE

Comment: @UniversE, as I stated `TO_CHAR` does not work for INTERVAL types and the format of INTERVAL types is fix, i.e. cannot be changed by any NLS_xxx or other personal settings. Do you have a better idea?

Comment: See Multisync's or my answer. It's not, that it doesn't work or that it can be broken by NLS settings. It's about style and bypassing the type system.

Comment: Yes.. I saw .. that.
Thank you very much.. again ... Very Helpful :)